# What the best strategy to structure CSS in GWT?

Tags: css, gwt, styling

We have a medium size application with around 30 views. We have many CSS files laying around. Some are specialized (popup styles) but the rest contains style for different parts of the application, in addition of the style embedded in the *.ui.xml and it's start to get pretty messy.

Is there any guideline on how to structure the styling in a GWT application and in a web application in general ? How do you structure yours ?

Comment: It might help you to understand about [GWT Styling](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/style.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two schools of thought on this. Some developers prefer to use [CSS Resources](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResource).

My strong preference, after 7 years of experience with GWT and multiple projects, is to have a single external CSS file for all styles. I even do not include any GWT stylesheets (including DataGrid styles) - I copy their content into my CSS file. These are the reasons for this preference:

1. CSS is called a cascading style sheet for a reason - it is build around inheritance. A professional web designer builds an app design starting from the very top (html, body elements) and defines the rules for the entire application: font or fonts to be used, color palette, standard margins and paddings, standard grid (columns width), etc. These rules must propagate throughout the entire app. Once developers start defining their own styles at the view/widget level, it's nearly impossible to ensure any design consistency across the app.
2. Even more importantly, when the CSS rules are split between many different sources, it becomes very hard to predict their interactions. Why is this element not positioned correctly or has the wrong font size? Is it because I used the wrong selector in the widget CSS, or is this because some other rule from some other CSS resource overrides or conflicts with it? Now you find yourself jumping back and forth between different stylesheets trying to make it work.
3. Even if you do find a source of the problem and fix it in one of the stylesheets, now you have to check how this change affected other views and widgets. Making a change at the top of the DOM tree can impact every element at the bottom (again, it's cascading!). Often it's not easy to anticipate this impact in every browser possible.
4. These considerations become even more important when you try to make your app design responsive and make your app adjust nicely to different screen sizes. What happens to your view or widget-level CSS when you add a media query in your main CSS file?
5. Another important point is the speed of development. If you use a professionally designed CSS file, you almost *do not need* CSS at a view or widget level. When I add a new form, for example, I never need any CSS - I just throw a sequence of labels and input widgets and they all suddenly look right and they are positioned correctly, because the rules have been already set and they apply to all forms, input elements, labels, etc. in the app. I do not think what font size or color to use in a widget. I just use a `<h2>` header, for example, and it has one color in a light skin and a different color in a dark skin, and it changes its size and margins according to the screen size.
6. Finally, moving as much CSS away from the widgets makes it easier to reuse them in new projects. Using the same example, if a header does not have a font-family, font-size, color or margins specified in a widget, it will take these values from another app's CSS file (which may or may not be the same rules as the contributing project's file). So you can reuse the widget in a new project without touching its code, which again speeds up the development process and makes maintenance so much easier.

To summarize, a single CSS file makes it easier to enforce style consistency across the entire app and maintain code, and considerably speeds up the development.

Comment: Having a single CSS file looks interesting because you would have a unique place for styling, also it would be faster to load as a resource, but in other hand, the file would be huge and not easely readable. What do you do to improve the readability ?

Comment: Hire a good designer :)  Most CSS files get huge because developers create many redundant rules at the level of individual views and components, as opposed to creating high-level rules that apply to many elements at once. Also, GWT provides an excellent opportunity to create widgets that extend other widgets. For example, if you create a widget MyDialogBox (and set all the styles on it) and then make every dialog in your app extend it (or simply provide a body to it), you can make a large part of your app look very consistent with just a few lines of CSS. Same with views, forms, toolbars, etc.