# Apply styles to GWT widgets

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder, cssresource

I have just started to explore GWT, and i'm bit confused with different ways of applying styles to GWT widgets.In gwt docs, there are 4 ways by which you can override default style of a widget,

1) Using a  tag in the host HTML page.(Deprecated)
2) Using the  element in the module XML file.(Deprecated)
3) Using a CssResource contained within a ClientBundle.
4) Using an inline  element in a UiBinder template.

Suppose i have a CSS file in some package say, com.abc.xyz.styles.css .And the file has the following contents,

```
/**the panel itself**/
.gwt-TabLayoutPanel {
    border: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
/**the tab bar element**/
.gwt-TabLayoutPanel .gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabs {
    background-color: #F4F4F4 !important;
}
/**an individual tab**/
.gwt-TabLayoutPanel .gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab {
    background-color: #6F6F6E !important;
}

.gwt-TabLayoutPanel .gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab-selected {
    background-color: white !important;
}
/**an element nested in each tab (useful for styling)**/
.gwt-TabLayoutPanel .gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner {
    font-family: Arial !important;
}

/**applied to all child content widgets**/
.gwt-TabLayoutPanel .gwt-TabLayoutPanelContent {
    border: none;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

How will i inject this css file ? How can this be done using the 3rd and 4th option of styling mentioned above?.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your CSS file to the host page. Then you can use the full power of CSS selectors. This is my preferred method of using CSS in GWT:

[What the best strategy to structure CSS in GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898319/what-the-best-strategy-to-structure-css-in-gwt/23898888#23898888)

Comment: It would be useful , if you can give an example for my case mentioned in the question using client bundle + css resources..

Comment: I do not use these options - I find them too slow in development and hard to maintain compared to a stand-alone CSS file.